# Load a particular version of a class when Autoload is used

Tags: php, oop, autoload

Consider a large application which autoloads classes as such:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    require_once("/var/www/application/classes/{$class}.php");
}
```

There may be tens of files which use the class, all of which relied on a particular bug in the class. Now that I've fixed the bug, I need to update all the places where the class is called.

From within the class, I would like to whitelist known-fixed places where the class is called from where I have fixed the bug. For the un-whitelisted places, I would replicate the old behaviour and in the whitelisted places I would give the correct behaviour. **Is there a clean way to do this?**

I was thinking about adding a new constructor argument `$useFixedVersion` for the duration of the fix (which might take a few days), and then going back and removing that argument afterwards. However, this means that I need to go over each place *twice* and it seems a rather bad workaround. **Is there a better way to detect from where the class is being called?** Consider that both instance and static methods are affected.

Let us ignore the coupling and bad code design for a moment which means that I need to correct the calling code, and take this unfortunate fact as a given. Let us also ignore the unfortunate fact that I cannot simple branch off in Git, make my fixes, and then push to production!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `debug_backtrace()` function, which would allow you to know where things are getting called from:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

That said, have you considered using namespaces for this? Something like:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;
class FixedBaz extends Baz {}
```

And then alias the classes as needed:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;
use FixedBaz as Baz;
```

Comment: Thank you Denis. It looks like debug_backtrace() will do perfectly. I don't see using namespaces as a good workaround either.